# output row with greatest date mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next table where I want to retrieve the row with status=4 and the greatest date

**TABLE**

```
status  date
  4      2018-11-25
  3      2018-11-24
  4      2018-11-22
```

Expected Output

```
4 2018-11-25
```

I have tried this statement but it return error

**SQL**

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM posts 
  WHERE status=4 AND MAX(date)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and fetch the most recent row.  In standard SQL, this would be:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts p
WHERE p.status = 4 
ORDER BY date DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

`FETCH FIRST` is standard SQL for this construct.  Some databases uses `SELECT TOP (1)` or `LIMIT` or even other methods.  MySQL uses `LIMIT` instead of `FETCH FIRST`.

You cannot use aggregation functions in a `WHERE` clause.  You *can* use them in a `HAVING` clause after a `GROUP BY`, but that logic is not appropriate.

Comment: Ok. thank you, I understand, but Can I use `LIMIT 1` instead of `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;`?

Comment: @Joe Yes, you may use just `LIMIT 1` after the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using a subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE
    status = 4 AND
    date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM posts WHERE status = 4);
```

### Demo

If you are using MySQL 8+ or later, then we can take advantage of analytic functions:

```
SELECT status, date
FROM
(
    SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM posts p
    WHERE status = 4
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select status, max(Date) from table where status =4 group by status;`

> This would rather be simple with just a group by which groups the status and calculates maximum of the dates within each group as you wanted just for status 4 ,where clause was used to filter out only for status =4